# Chunk data and Display with header in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-views

I have data that I need to display in 3 rows with header in Laravel blade view.I know there is chunk method in Laravel to chunk the data and display.But I want to diplay data in different way.

**Here is my data**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1898 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
  0 => {#1021 ▼
  +"parameter": "NH3 Examine"
  +"id": 6
  +"pond_quality_id": 5
  +"parameter_id": 28
  +"pond_water_cig": 12
  +"pond_water_non_cig": 12
  +"taken_actions_cig": 12
  +"taken_actions_non_cig": 12
  +"taken_actions": "action"
  +"measure_before_intervention": "before"
  +"measure_after_intervention": "after"
  +"remarks": "remarks1"
  +"created_at": "2021-04-25 10:16:00"
  +"updated_at": "2021-04-25 10:16:00"
}
1 => {#1897 ▼
  +"parameter": "O2 Examine"
  +"id": 7
  +"pond_quality_id": 5
  +"parameter_id": 29
  +"pond_water_cig": 23
  +"pond_water_non_cig": 23
  +"taken_actions_cig": 23
  +"taken_actions_non_cig": 23
  +"taken_actions": "action taken"
  +"measure_before_intervention": "before intervention"
  +"measure_after_intervention": "after intervention"
  +"remarks": "remarks2"
  +"created_at": "2021-04-25 10:16:00"
  +"updated_at": "2021-04-25 10:16:00"
}
]
}
```

**Here is how I want to output my data**

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col1 val1 | col2 val1 | col3 val3 | col4 val4 |
| col1 val2 | col2 val2 | col3 val3 | col4 val4 |

| col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col5 val1 | col6 val1 | col7 val3 | col8 val4 |
| col5 val2 | col6 val2 | col7 val3 | col8 val4 |

| col9 |
| --- |
| col9 val1 |
| col9 val2 |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have `$loop` in scope for every `@foreach` loop you use in blade, that also scales with loops inside of loops

Here's an example of how you could achieve what you want; every 3rd row, add a header of your choice. You might need to play with the modulus there - I'm sure 3 is correct, but considering `$loop->iteration` starts at 1, not 0, I could be wrong.

Please see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade for more usages of `$loop variable` within the context of `@foreach`

```
@foreach($items as $item)

    @if($loop->iteration % 3 == 0)
        //output header row
    @endif

    //output $item

@endforeach
```

You need to define yourself a set of rules for your header rows, considering you have 3 identical tables, but your fourth seems to have 1 header and is unique, you may want to create a helper function that allows you to include a view dependant on the iteration using more than one `@if` statement in your blade.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to achieve the expected result is chunks function. Simple and clean.

```
    @foreach($items->chunk(2) as $chunk)
      <div class="s-table-container">
        <table class="s-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>parameter</th>
              <th>pond_quality_id</th>
              <th>pond_water_cig</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             @foreach($chunk as $item)
               <tr>
                 <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
                 <td>{{$item->parameter}}</td>
                 <td>{{$item->pond_quality_id}}</td>
                 <td>{{$item->pond_water_cig}}</td>
               </tr>
             @endforeach
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     @endforeach
```